# unsupported operand type python tkinter with addition in intval

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a cookie clicker type game with tkinter and whenever I do addition with the IntVal it says unsupported operand type(s) for +:intvar and intvar

here is my code

```
 import tkinter as tk
 root = tk.Tk()

 def increment(var):
     var.set(var.get() + 1)
 def cookie(var):
     cookies.set(cookies.get() + clicker.get())
 cookies = tk.IntVar()
 clicker = tk.IntVar()
 tk.Button(root, text="cookies", command=lambda: increment(cookies)).pack()
 tk.Label(root, textvariable=cookies).pack()
 tk.Button(root, text="clicker", command=lambda: increment(clicker)).pack()
 tk.Label(root, textvariable=clicker).pack()
 cookies = cookies + clicker
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove the line `cookies = cookies + clicker`.

Comment: that would get  rid of the error but i still need to do that for the actual idea to work is there an alternative way

Comment: You should use `cookie()` function for that purpose and call it whenever you want.

Comment: what condition would i call it with tho

Comment: It depends on your game design that I don't have idea.  When will this addition be performed in your game design?

Comment: well that is the entire script
that will be called every 10s or so to add the number of clickers you have to your total
like in cookieclicker

Comment: I still don't get what your game design.  Do you mean that there is system scheduler to execute your script every 10s?  But your script will create a GUI window, that means every 10s a new GUI window will be created?

Comment: no i meant the function runs every 10s

Comment: Then update your code to show how you execute the function (which function?) every 10s.

Comment: the function is cookie. i got an irl frend to fix it but this rly helped thx

Comment: btw if You want to have an "independent" loop when using tkinter look up `after()` method

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
def increment(var):
    var.set(var.get()+1)
def cookie(var):
    cookies.set(cookies.get() + clicker.get())
cookies = tk.IntVar()
clicker = tk.IntVar()
tk.Button(root, text="cookies", command=lambda: increment(cookies)).pack()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=cookies).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="clicker", command=lambda: increment(clicker)).pack()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=clicker).pack()

root.mainloop()
```